# End of Statement Expected Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net

Error that I get:

> Error 1   End of statement
>   expected. c:\users\blahblahblah\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    12  75  WindowsApplication1

Code that I use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("s­amp://" + TextBox1.Text + "")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500) SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}") SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: in addition to the answer below, you can also separate commands on one line using colons as such (although for readability this isn't always a great idea): `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500) : SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}") : SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")`

Answer (score 1):

start each statement in new line

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("s­amp://" + TextBox1.Text + "") 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500) 
SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}") 
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```